# Excel 2010 VBA/MACRO lookup field value to auto create statement

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I need a macro/vba which can auto create a select stamen based on the value in the excel. Example as below. The query can hardcode as 'SELECT * FROM PRDTBL WHERE' the remaining part should handle by macro where it will based on the value in A01,A02 and A03. IF one of the value is blank then it will be ignore. Anyone can give me an ideas/Link on how to achieve it ? Thanks

```
ID      QUERY                                                                   A01     A02     A03     Remark
1001    SELECT * FROM PRDTBL WHERE A01='ASIA' AND A02='MACHINE' AND A03='G1234' ASIA    MACHINE G1234   
1001    SELECT * FROM PRDTBL WHERE A01='EURO' AND A02='MACHINE' AND A03='F101'  EURO    MACHINE F101    
1004    SELECT * FROM PRDTBL WHERE A01='EURO' AND A03='ASS1'                    EURO    ASS1    
1003    SELECT * FROM PRDTBL WHERE A01='LATIN' AND A02='FURNITURE'              LATIN   FURNITURE       
1005    SELECT * FROM PRDTBL WHERE A01='AUS'                                    AUS
```

Comment: `Anyone can give me an ideas/Link on how to achieve it ?` Er, record a macro?

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For something quick like this I would just create a formula and use the "&" symbol to concatenate the strings together:

```
="SELECT * FROM PRDTBL WHERE "&IF(B1="","","A01 = '"&B1&"'")&IF(C1="","",IF(B1<>""," AND ","")&"A02 = '"&C1&"'")&IF(D1="","",IF(OR(B1<>"",C1<>"")," AND ","")& "A03 = '"&D1&"'")
```

Comment: thank for your idea, it look good but how to write a condition if previous fields is blank? example if field 1 is blank then 'AND A01=&A01&' else 'A01=&A01&'.

Comment: No problem. From your example I assumed that A01 would always be populated if A02 also was. I just made some modifications to get rid of the "AND" when it's not needed.